# use the zip command specifying different path from current directory

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, zip

We have a set of unix tools that were ported to windows and I want to use the zip command to package a set of files.

I'm trying to do this:

- Open cmd from desktop and take the files in `r:\pam\client\ssb\portfoliorepportcards\202003\*.docx` and create a zip file in `r:\pam\client\ssb\PortfolioReportCards\202003.zip` with the files in it.

My command is:

```
C:\Users\JPalomino\Desktop>zip.exe -b "r:\pam\client\ssb\PortfolioReportCards" 202003.zip . -i r:\pam\client\ssb\portfoliorepportcards\202003\*.docx
```

> zip error: Nothing to do! (202003.zip)

and I get nothing

However when I `cd to r:\pam\client\ssb\portfoliorepportcards` and do

```
R:\Pam\Client\SSB\PortfolioReportCards>zip -r 202003.zip . -i \202003\*.docx
```

it works like a charm. Also I wouldn't want the folder structure in it.

Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong in the command? It seems such an easy thing to ask from zip.

Thanks

Comment: Well, the single dot means current directory. You don't want to compress files in current directory into the ZIP file. You want to compress files in `R:\pam\client\ssb\portfoliorepportcards\202003` into the ZIP file. So what you most likely need is `zip.exe "R:\pam\client\ssb\PortfolioReportCards\202003.zip" "R:\pam\client\ssb\portfoliorepportcards\202003\*.docx"` or `zip.exe "R:\pam\client\ssb\PortfolioReportCards\202003.zip" "R:\pam\client\ssb\portfoliorepportcards\202003" -i *.docx` according to the [manual for zip](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zip).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help, you don't need zip.exe (if you have powershell 5 or higher)...

```
powershell -command "Compress-Archive -Path 'r:\pam\client\ssb\PortfolioReportCards\*' 'r:\pam\client\ssb\PortfolioReportCards\202003.zip'"
```

I saw you're having trouble zipping to another drive letter, this should help with that too. I'm not really familiar with zip.exe to know why that's giving your grief.

Anything else you "port" to cmd is probably better off as a powershell. --- also if "zip.exe" isn't on your desktop that could possibly be your problem right there. If it works when you CD that tells me it's probably located where you're CD'ing to. Perhaps add zip.exe as an environment variable so that it can be accessed globally instead of only from the working directory.

---

And my take one your command (If zip is actually on your desktop or set as environment variable... : `zip.exe -b "r:\pam\client\ssb\PortfolioReportCards" 202003.zip . -i r:\pam\client\ssb\portfoliorepportcards\202003\*.docx`

I would re-write that and try this instead (because traditionally the filepath is all in quotes for any other windows command I know of)...
`zip.exe -b "r:\pam\client\ssb\PortfolioReportCards\202003.zip" . -i r:\pam\client\ssb\portfoliorepportcards\202003\*.docx`